# Why does template stuff still appear after uninstall [helixultimate]

Tags: development, templates, debug

I installed the site template Helixultimate. Some time later, I removed it by `Manage Extension`.

Then, I logged stuff inside of `SiteMenu.php` and found e.g. `helixultimatemenulayout` inside the `params` parameter.

**Doesn't get everything uninstalled, once I uninstall a component?
And does this kind of fallout may render problems?**

Log from inside `SiteMenu.php`:

```
        Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem Object ( 
    [id] => 394 
    [menutype] => mainmenu 
    [title] => rr 
    [alias] => rr 
    [note] => 
    [route] => rr 
    [link] => index.php?option=com_eventcalendar&view=featured 
    [type] => component 
    [level] => 1 
    [language] => * 
    [browserNav] => 0 
    [access] => 1 
    [params:protected] => {"show_feed_image":"","menu-anchor_title":"","menu-anchor_css":"","menu_icon_css":"","menu_image":"","menu_image_css":"","menu_text":1,"menu_show":1,"page_title":"","show_page_heading":"","page_heading":"","pageclass_sfx":"","menu-meta_description":"","robots":"",
"helixultimatemenulayout":"",
"helixultimate_enable_page_title":"0",
"helixultimate_page_title_alt":"",
"helixultimate_page_subtitle":"",
"helixultimate_page_title_heading":"h2",
"helixultimate_page_title_bg_color":"",
"helixultimate_page_title_bg_image":""} 
    [home] => 0 
    [img] => [template_style_id] => 0 
    [component_id] => 287 [parent_id] => 1 
    [component] => com_eventcalendar [tree] => Array ( ) 
    [query] => Array ( ) 
    [_parent:protected] => 
    [_children:protected] => Array ( ) 
    [_leftSibling:protected] => 
    [_rightSibling:protected] => 
    )
```

Additionally, this stuff exists in cache - even after I cleared it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Doesn't get everything uninstalled, once I uninstall a component? And
> does this kind of fallout may render problems?"

When you uninstall any extension(component, template,plugin,etc) the details in manifest file, extensionwhatever.xml, that was used to install the extension is used to remove the directories and files that were installed and the entry for the extension in the #__extensions table is removed. Assuming there is no special script running when the extension is uninstalled that is all the uninstall normally does.

It is not practical to program the uninstall process to search for other references to said extension, correctly determine the right action to take and then understand what the correct process is to remove that reference from other extensions.

In your case a number of parameters stored amongst others in a field of a table for com_menu. If they were removed automatically would your menu item fail to load or function?

In this case you were expecting every reference of Helix to be removed because you no longer wanted to use the template(s). However there may be a instance where someone might want to uninstall Helix so you can re-install a fresh version of Helix, in that instance you would not want to have it removed from all your menus or you would have to manually re-add Helix to all your menus.

The purpose and type of extension really determines whether there are going to be orphaned artefacts left over in your site, particularly references added to other extensions.

And yes this approach can cause problems having references to an extension that no longer exists that will either result is obvious error or warning messages while at other times they will just appear as a benign pieces of dust accumulating around you site.

Answer (score 1):

The Helix Ultimate framework plugin is also installed when installing Helix Ultimate templates.

Check that the framework plugin has also been removed.

Comment: Unter System > Plugins, search for hell doesn't find anything.

Comment: Neil, could you please explain, why this Joomla.stackexchange.com site exists? Where should I post? At SO or at Joomla.SO?

Comment: Found the source: These values come from params field of entries in the so93c_menu table: "helixultimatemenulayout":"","helixultimate_enable_page_title":"0","helixultimate_page_title_alt":"","helixultimate_page_subtitle":"","helixultimate_page_title_heading":"h2","helixultimate_page_title_bg_color":"","helixultimate_page_title_bg_image":""}

Comment: For questions about JSE itself, please ask a new question on [meta.joomla.se].